# How can I add a LINQ to XML subquery to a LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I have an XML structure in a databse column of type XML that looks something like this:

```
<Translation>
   <Language ID="1">
       <Title>Some title</Title>
       <Abbrevation>some abbrevation</Abbrevation>
       <Source>https://www.somesource.com</Source>
   </Language>
   <Language ID="2">
       <Title>some more titles</Title>
       <Abbrevation>some more abbrevation</Abbrevation>
       <Source>https://www.somemoresource.com</Source>
          </Sprache>
</Translation>
```

Now I need to get elements of this XML into a LINQ to Entities query.
What I tried so far:

```
return from x in _context.Test
               where((displayAll == false && (x.Aufhebung == null || x.Aufhebung > DateTime.Now)) || (displayAll))
               select new TestViewModel()
               {
                   ID = x.ID,
                   Prop = x.Prop,
                   Number = x.Number ?? "",
                   Title = XElement.Parse(x.Translation).Descendants("Language").Where(f => f.FirstAttribute.Value == "1").Descendants("Title").Single().Value,
               };
    }
```

and the property on the model is:

```
public string Translation{ get; set; }
```

But I always get the error-message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method [System.Xml.Linq.XElement], System.Xml.Linq.XName, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there a way to get a LINQ to XML subquery in LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a "database element" is not materialized, every expression in Linq methods will be translated as a SQL Expression, when possible... but this operation:

```
Title = XElement.Parse(x.Translation).Descendants("Language").Where(f => f.FirstAttribute.Value == "1").Descendants("Title").Single().Value
```

as the message text of the error says, cannot be translated in a store expression, that's because of the presence of XElement and its methods.

To execute this line in a Linq Method, you must materialize the IQueryable returned by

```
context.Test.where((displayAll == false && (x.Aufhebung == null || x.Aufhebung > DateTime.Now)) || (displayAll))
```

and then proceed with that select. In this case, to materialize this IQueryable, in the Non-SQL like syntax Linq provide the Method .ToList() that in this case would return a List< Test>, materialized and ready on the application memory to be used with every application expression.